# Angularjs: Call a function when ever a certain type of route is invoked

Tags: angularjs

Following is my sample route config.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/admin', {
        templateUrl: 'admin/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
    }).when('/admin/confrence',{
        templateUrl: 'admin/adminconfrence.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
    }).when('/admin/confrence/new',{
        templateUrl: 'admin/adminconfrencenew.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
    });
}])
```

I want to do some authentication check when ever any route is called which is beginning  `/admin`. Can someone please guide me how it's possible

Comment: I think you should use [the `resolve` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for the route to do your authentication check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {       
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf("/admin")!= -1){
           // do your stuff
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the route from loading.

Comment: i think we have to change "new.indexOf" to "next.$$route.originalPath". 
If possible please update your answer so that i can mark it as right answer.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood thanks for pointing out. Updated. Did you mean that?

Comment: what i meant was. `next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf("/admin")!= -1`